# How do I add a right button to a UINavigationController that pushes another view controller?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a view controller connected to a navigation controller.  I want to add a right button to the navigation bar on the top that will push another view controller.  If I add the right button with:

```
UIBarButtonItem *Button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Map" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:[self forward]];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = Button;
```

the button appears.  However, if I add the following lines to the forward method, the button disappears again:

```
MapViewController *viewController = [self.navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"map"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: remove this action:[self forward] and try action: @selector(forward)

Comment: MapViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"map"];  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"map" sender:self]; then write this code in forward method

Answer (score 1):

there is a problem with the line `action:[self forward]]` while declaring `UIBarButtonItem` in your code...change it to `@selector(forward)` or try this

```
UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showNextVC)];          
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nextButton;
```

and in `showNextVC:`

```
-(void) showNextVC {
 MapViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"map"];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I think he is not using navigation in storyboard. so we could use self.navigationController pushViewController. Instead, [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];

Comment: in the first line he mentioned that view is embedded in navigationcontroller and he wants to push another viewcontroller on rightbarbutton click

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
UIImage *rightBtnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bulb-plus.png"];
UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[rightButton setImage:rightBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 26, 35);

[rightButton addTarget:self
               action:@selector(rightBarButtonAction)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem;
```

IBAction method for rightBarbutton

```
- (void)rightBarButtonAction {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"IdeaDetailSegue" sender:self];
}
```

Hope this helps.